# C++ Как отследить нажатие кнопки PrintScreen

Tags: c++, клавиатура, key, hotkeys

Подскажите как можно отследить нажатие кнопки на клавиатуре принт скрин, и после выполнить какое то действие, например просто вывести сообщение в консоль

Comment: ключевой фактор, от которого очень сильно зависит ответ — операционная система. которую вы не укзали.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (getch() == 44)
{
        cout << "Hello!";
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]